# Watson Speech to Text API for Dutch Language support with Node.js

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

At present `Watson Speech-to-Text` API supports only Brazilian Portuguese, French, Japanese, Mandarin Chinese, Modern Standard Arabic, Spanish, UK English, and US English.

Is there any alternative way to make API support for **`Dutch language`** with `Watson Speech-to-text` API?

If not, is there any planned release which could support **`Dutch language`** ? Whom to request for inclusion of this in the next release ?

Checkout and support for inclusion of [Dutch Language Watson Speech-to-Text API service](https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas/suggestions/15259455-availability-of-dutch-language-support-in-watson-s)

Comment: Hello Prasanta K Chakravarty, let me get this information for you...

Answer (score 0):

Current Watson Speech to Text does not provide any alternative to support Dutch language. We do not comment on our future roadmap as it is subject to change but please reach out to me directly to talk in more detail about inclusion of this request.

Comment: `@Bhavik Shah`, Thanks very much for the responce. It will be nice if you could please give me your contact detail, so that I can reach out to you for a discussion.